# Calcule las diferencias entre las celdas en un marco de datos de dos resultados de columna "debe ser un vector atómico 1d o una lista"

Tags: r, group-by

Quiero calcular las diferencias entre celdas en un marco de datos de una columna.

```
> head(df_benchmark)
        Date .STOXXR
1 2000-01-03  478.52
2 2000-01-04  459.53
3 2000-01-05  448.19
4 2000-01-06  446.24
5 2000-01-07  455.80
6 2000-01-10  462.97
```

El archivo esta [aquí](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MExW-r0NNGAlMxlQh_tjOscpm6xBiMsfMKRPQykJgr8/edit?usp=sharing).

Así que intenté lo siguiente:

```
> df_benchmark <- read.xlsx("Data.xlsx", sheet = "Benchmark", startRow = 2,colNames = TRUE, detectDates = TRUE, skipEmptyRows = FALSE)
> df_benchmark[2] <- data.matrix(df_benchmark[2])

> library(lubridate)
> percent_change2 <- function(x)last(x)/first(x) - 1
> monthly_return_benchmark <- df_benchmark %>% 
+   group_by(gr = floor_date(Date, unit = "month")) %>%
+   summarize_at(vars(-Date, -gr), percent_change2) %>%
+   ungroup() %>%
+   select(-gr) %>% 
+   as.matrix()
```

Sin embargo, tengo un error. Parece que mi marco de datos con una columna de fechas y una columna de valores debe ser un vector o lista atómica 1d. Parece que la razón es un problema de variables:

```
Error: Each variable must be a 1d atomic vector or list.
Problem variables: '.STOXXR'
```

## Segunda intento

Así que probé también el siguiente código:

```
library(xts)
df_benchmark <- read.xlsx("Data.xlsx", sheet = "Benchmark", startRow = 2,colNames = TRUE, detectDates = TRUE, skipEmptyRows = FALSE)

percent_change2 <- function(x) last(x)/first(x) - 1
monthly_return_benchmark <- df_benchmark %>% 
  group_by(gr = floor_date(as_date(Date), unit = "month")) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(-Date, -gr), percent_change2) %>%
  ungroup()

# Generamos el xts, indicando la columna con la info de tiempo
monthly_return_benchmark <- xts(monthly_return[,-1], order.by=monthly_return$gr)
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

```
> library(xts)
> df_benchmark <- read.xlsx("Data.xlsx", sheet = "Benchmark", startRow = 2,colNames = TRUE, detectDates = TRUE, skipEmptyRows = FALSE)
> 
> percent_change2 <- function(x) last(x)/first(x) - 1
> monthly_return_benchmark <- df_benchmark %>% 
+   group_by(gr = floor_date(as_date(Date), unit = "month")) %>%
+   summarize_at(vars(-Date, -gr), percent_change2) %>%
+   ungroup()
Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

## Tercera intento

Solo usando el `group_by` usando los meses como unidades obtengo lo siguiente:

```
> monthly_return_benchmark <- df_benchmark %>% 
+     group_by(gr = floor_date(Date, unit = "month"))
> monthly_return_benchmark
Source: local data frame [4,604 x 3]
Groups: gr [216]

         Date .STOXXR         gr
       <date>   <chr>     <date>
1  2000-01-03  478.52 2000-01-01
2  2000-01-04  459.53 2000-01-01
3  2000-01-05  448.19 2000-01-01
4  2000-01-06  446.24 2000-01-01
5  2000-01-07   455.8 2000-01-01
6  2000-01-10  462.97 2000-01-01
7  2000-01-11  459.85 2000-01-01
8  2000-01-12  459.84 2000-01-01
9  2000-01-13  462.27 2000-01-01
10 2000-01-14  473.43 2000-01-01
# ... with 4,594 more rows
```

Ahora tengo que hacer el `percent_change2` pero nunca funcionó.

#### Actualización

No sé porqué pero apareció un nueva error. Parece que `df_benchmark`no tiene un `appropriate time-based object`

```
> df_benchmark %>% 
+   #mutate(.STOXXR = as.numeric(.STOXXR)) %>%                    #Corrige el problema leyendo con read.excel (no testeado)
+   group_by(gr = floor_date(as_date(Date), unit = "month")) %>%
+   summarize(retorno = last(.STOXXR)/first(.STOXXR) -1) %>%      #Defino la función directamente acá
+   ungroup() -> monthly_return_benchmark                         #Asigno nombre al final
> 
> monthly_return_benchmark <- xts(monthly_return[,-1], order.by=monthly_return$gr) #No testeado, no uso esa librería#No testeado, no uso esa librería
Error in xts(monthly_return[, -1], order.by = monthly_return$gr) : 
  order.by requires an appropriate time-based object
```

Pienso que hay un error: debe ser utilizado:

```
monthly_return_benchmark <- xts(monthly_return_benchmark[,-1], order.by=monthly_return_benchmark$gr) #No testeado, no uso esa librería#No testeado, no uso esa librería
```

Comment: .STOXXR debe ser numérica. Si te fijas en el tibble de tu tercer intento aparece como `character`, por eso no te pasa el error de `non-numeric`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer el problema es que `.STOXXR` se importa desde el Excel como `character`, cuando debería ser `numeric`. Por eso `summarise` pasa el error

```
Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

que en realidad lo produce internamente `percent_change2`. Como es evaluación no estándar es muy difícil rastrearlo a partir del mensaje del error.

La buena práctica es especificar los tipos de cada columna directamente en la importación para evitar tener que cambiar el tipo más adelante en el código y estar rastreando lesos cambios. Sobre todo porque algunas funciones de R tienen reglas de coerción internas diferentes a las demás. Entonces con algunas funciones las cosas andan, con otras obtienes un error.

Va una solución importando los datos con `read_excel()` en la que se importa con los tipos de datos correctos para cada columna.

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

#Leo el Excel con read_excel, porque estoy más familiarizado
df_benchmark <- read_excel("DataPassenger.xlsx", 
                           sheet = "Benchmark", 
                           col_types = c("date", "numeric"), #Importo cada columna con la clase correcta, acá estaba el problema
                           skip = 1)

df_benchmark %>% 
  #mutate(.STOXXR = as.numeric(.STOXXR)) %>%                    #Corrige el problema leyendo con read.excel (no testeado)
  group_by(gr = floor_date(as_date(Date), unit = "month")) %>%
  summarize(retorno = last(.STOXXR)/first(.STOXXR) -1) %>%      #Defino la función directamente acá
  ungroup() -> monthly_return                                   #Asigno nombre al final

monthly_return_benchmark <- xts(monthly_return[,-1], order.by=monthly_return$gr) #No testeado, no uso esa librería
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Parece que el problemo es esto. Sin embargo, al intentar con el suyo codigo obtengo `Error in read.xlsx("Data.xlsx", sheet = "Benchmark", col_types = c("date",  : 
  unused argument (col_types = c("date", "numeric"))` al leer los datos del archivo excel... Me disculpe. No había la librería `readxl`

Comment: Debes usar la función `read_excel()` de la librería `readxl::`. Fíjate que tiene una guión bajo, no un punto. `read.excel()` es un función diferente que no reconoce esos argumentos.

Comment: Si, obtengo `Error: could not find function "read_excel"` mientras que obtenia `package ‘readxl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked`... Logré obtenerlo con `readxl::read_excel(...`

Comment: Prueba usar tu código original de importación que usa `read.excel()` y descomentar a segunda línea de mi solución `mutate(.STOXXR ...)` para hacer la transformación a numérica ahí. Alternativamente: no olvides ejecutar `library(readxl)`, quizás por eso no encuentre la función `read_excel`

Comment: Lo siento muchísimo pero tengo una nueva error. Parece que `monthly_return` no tiene un `appropriate time-based object`. Por lo tanto, todo funciona antes. Pienso que hay un error en la última línea. Actualicé la pregunta.

Comment: Ya lo arreglé, había confundido los nombres asignados al objeto agregando `_benchmark`, que era el del objeto siguiente. Con el código de la respuesta ahora funciona.